# Issue with where to print an error message when user inputs invalid rationals

Tags: c++, class, ostream, istream

I have three files all related to created a rational/fractional class to do operations with. My issue is I am trying to print "Invalid Rational Format" when user types in incorrect rationals (ex: 1/-.8, 3/-4)
Naturally I assume I would place this message in the istream function in the !isvalid section since incorrect rationals are invalid. In addition to this the output value must be defaulted to 0/1 since user input is not valid. However, as shown in the picture even when I type valid inputs the message prints, so I am not sure where I should include this message.
[image]

// where I tried inserting message and defaulting the input
if(!isvalid)
        {

```
       ins.setstate(ios::failbit);
       //r.numerator = 0;
      // r.denominator = 1;
       // cout << "Invalid Rational format!\n";
       // str = "0/1";
        //isitvalid = false;
        return ins;
    }
```

```
// Add appropriate headers

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


/*  KEEP THIS COMMENT
* class Rational
*    represents a Rational number. Remember rational means ratio-nal
*    which means there is a numerator and denominator having
*    integer values. Using good ADT techniques, we have made member
*    variable private (also known as instance variables) and made member
*    functions public.
*/
class Rational
{
 private:   
  int numerator;
  int denominator;
  static int counter;
  //function that simplifies and will be called by simplify
  int gcd (int a, int b);



 public:
    /*
    // ToDo: Default Constructor
    Rational();

    // ToDo: Constructor that takes int numerator
    Rational(int num);

    // ToDo: Constructor that takes int numerator and int denominator
    Rational(int num, int den);
    */
    // Three constructors to one 
    Rational(int num = 0, int den = 1);

    string convert_decimal(string str);

    // ToDo: Member function to read a rational in the form: n/d
    void input(Rational &a, Rational &b);

    // ToDo: Member function to write a rational as n/d
    void output()const;

    // ToDo: declare an accessor function to get the numerator
    int getNumerator()const;

    // ToDo: declare an accessor function to get the denominator
    int getDenominator()const;

    // object counter 'global'
    static int getObjectCounter();

    // ToDo: delcare a function called Sum that takes two rational objects
    // sets the current object to the sum of the given objects using the
    // formula: a/b + c/d = ( a*d + b*c)/(b*sd)
    //funtion to add rationals
    friend Rational operator + (const Rational &a, const Rational &b);

    //function to mutiply rationals
    friend Rational operator * (const Rational &a, const Rational &b);

    friend Rational operator / (const Rational &a, const Rational &b);

    friend Rational operator - (const Rational &a, const Rational &b);
    friend bool operator == (const Rational &a, const Rational &b);

    friend bool operator != (const Rational &a, const Rational &b);

    friend bool operator < (const Rational &a, const Rational &b);

    friend bool operator <= (const Rational &a, const Rational &b);

    friend bool operator > (const Rational &a, const Rational &b);

    friend bool operator >= (const Rational &a, const Rational &b);

    friend bool isnegative (const Rational &a, const Rational &b);

    //isdigit;
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& ins, Rational &r);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& outs, const Rational& r);

    //funtion to set values in array
    void set(int num, int den);

    //function to simplify a rational
    void simplify();

    //friend bool isEqual(const Rational &a, const Rational &b);



};
```

```
// Add appropriate headers

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "rational8.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream> 
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


// ToDO: Implement your class member functions below.

/*
Rational::Rational()
{
   numerator = 0;
   denominator = 1;
}

Rational::Rational(int num)
{
   numerator = num;
   denominator = 1;
}

Rational::Rational(int num, int den)
{
   Rational r; 
   numerator = num;
   denominator = den;
}
*/

int Rational::counter = 0;

//Three constructors to one 
Rational::Rational(int num, int den)
{
    numerator = num;
    denominator = den;
    counter++;
}

string convert_decimal(string str)
{
    string Afterpoint = str.substr(str.find("."+1), (str.length()-1));
    return Afterpoint+"/100";

}

Rational operator + (const Rational &a, const Rational &b)
{
   Rational temp;
   int num = 0;
   int den = 0;

   num = (a.numerator*b.denominator + a.denominator*b.numerator);
   den = (a.denominator*b.denominator);

   temp.numerator = num;
   temp.denominator = den;

   return temp;

}


Rational operator * (const Rational &a, const Rational &b)
{
   Rational temp;

   //int num = (a.getNumerator()*b.getNumerator());
   //int den = (a.getDenominator()*b.getDenominator());
   int num = (a.numerator*b.numerator);
   int den = (a.denominator*b.denominator);
   temp.numerator = num;
   temp.denominator = den;

   return temp;
}

Rational operator - (const Rational &a, const Rational &b)
{
   Rational temp;
   int num = 0;
   int den = 0;

   num = (a.numerator*b.denominator - a.denominator*b.numerator);
   den = (a.denominator*b.denominator);

   temp.numerator = num;
   temp.denominator = den;

   return temp;
}


Rational operator / (const Rational &a, const Rational &b)
{
   Rational temp;

   int num = (a.numerator*b.denominator);
   int den = (a.denominator*b.numerator);
   temp.numerator = num;
   temp.denominator = den;

   return temp;

}

bool operator == (const Rational &a, const Rational &b)
{
  if (a.numerator * b.denominator == a.denominator * b.numerator)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}

bool operator != (const Rational &a, const Rational &b)
{
 if (a.numerator * b.denominator != a.denominator * b.numerator)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }

}

bool operator < (const Rational &a, const Rational &b)
{
  if (a.numerator * b.denominator < a.denominator * b.numerator)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}

// add or
bool operator <= (const Rational &a, const Rational &b)
{
  if ((a.numerator * b.denominator < a.denominator * b.numerator) || (a.numerator * b.denominator == a.denominator * b.numerator))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }

}

bool operator > (const Rational &a, const Rational &b)
{
  if (a.numerator * b.denominator > a.denominator * b.numerator)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }

}

//add or    
bool operator >= (const Rational &a, const Rational &b)
{
  if ((a.numerator * b.denominator > a.denominator * b.numerator) || (a.numerator * b.denominator == a.denominator * b.numerator))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}

/*
bool isEqual(const Rational &a, const Rational &b)
{
  if (a.numerator * b.denominator == a.denominator * b.numerator)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
*/

int Rational::getObjectCounter()
{
    return counter;
}


istream& operator >> (istream& ins, Rational &r)
{
    bool isnegative = false, slashfound = false, isvalid = true;
    string str;
    ins >> str;
    char dotfound = 'n';


    //if(str.find(".") == std::string::npos)
    for(int k = 0; k < str.length(); k++)
    {
        if(str[k] == '.')
            dotfound = 'y';

    }

    if(dotfound == 'y')
    {
       string AfterPoint = str.substr(str.find(".")+1,  (str.length() -1) ); // value after the decimal

        string BeforePoint = str.substr(0, str.find("."));
        //value before the decimal


        if(AfterPoint.length() == 1)
            str = BeforePoint+AfterPoint+"/10";
        else
            str = BeforePoint+AfterPoint+"/100";

        //cout << str;
        //cout << endl;


    }

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == '-')
        {
            if (i != 0)
                isvalid = false;
            else 
                isnegative = true;
        }
        else if(str[i] == '/')
        {
            if(i = 0 || (i == str.length()-1) || (isnegative && i == 1) || slashfound)
                isvalid = false;
            else
                slashfound = true;
        }
        else if(!isdigit(str[i]))
            isvalid = false;

        //if(!isvalid)
        //if(isvalid == false)
        if(!isvalid)
        {

           ins.setstate(ios::failbit);
           //r.numerator = 0;
          // r.denominator = 1;
           // cout << "Invalid Rational format!\n";
           // str = "0/1";
            //isitvalid = false;
            return ins;
        }

        istringstream istr(str);  

        if (slashfound)
        {
            int n, d;
            char c;
            istr >> n >> c >> d;
                if(d == 0)
                {
                    ins.setstate(ios::failbit);
                }
                else
                {
                    r.numerator = n;
                    //r.denominator = 1;  // slashfound
                    r.denominator = d;

                    if(dotfound == 'y')
                    {
                        r.simplify();
                        //cout << dotfound << " " << r << endl;
                    }      

                }
        }
        else // case where slash not found
        {
            istr >> r.numerator;
            r.denominator = 1;

        }

    }

    return ins;
}


ostream& operator << (ostream& outs, const Rational& r)
{
    outs << r.numerator << "/" << r.denominator;
    return outs;
}

/*
void Rational::output()const
{
   cout << numerator << "/" << denominator;
}
*/


void Rational::set(int num, int den)
{
    numerator = num;
    denominator = den;
}



// Two getter functions
int Rational::getNumerator()const
{
   return numerator;
}

int Rational::getDenominator()const
{
   return denominator;
}


void Rational::simplify()
{
    int x = gcd(numerator,denominator);
    if (x != 0)
    {
      numerator /= x;
      denominator /= x;
    }
    if(denominator < 0)
    {
        denominator = denominator * -1;
        numerator = numerator * -1;
    }
}


int Rational::gcd (int a, int b)
{
   while (a!=0 && b!=0)
   {
      a = a % b;
      if (a!=0)
         b = b % a;
   }
   if (a==0)
      return b;

   if (b==0)
      return a;
    return 0;
}
```

```
/* 
 * labrational8.cpp:
 *    A driver program that tests the class rational. This file contains your main function.
 *    The program should have a big main do-while loop that does the following:
 *      1. Give the user a list of operators and read in an operator. No numbers allowed.
 *      2. Validate that the operator is OK then read in the number of rational operands. Use the operator>>
 *      3. Apply the operator to the operands and print out the equation or relation with the result.
 *      4. Loop while the user says Continue?(y or n)
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include "rational8.h"
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int map_operator (string op);
// A Function that maps an operator string to a number for a switch statement

void evaluate_operator(int valid_op, Rational a, Rational b);
// A function that evaluates the operator described by the valid_op using operands a and b.

string operator_menu();
// A function that prints the operators in the order in which they appear in the map_opertor function.



//main program 



int main()
{
    Rational r1, r2, x;
    cout << "Welcome to Rational World!" <<endl;
    cout << endl;

    // Extra credit: in rational class operator>>
    // [5 pts] In the input operator>>, allow the user to enter the value as follows:
    //  0.45 - You should figure out the numerator is 45, denominator is 100. 
    //  0.3  - You should figure out the numerator is then 3, denominator is 10.

    char rerun;
    string opr ;
    int valid_op;


    do{
        // ToDo: Declare necessary local variables

        // ToDo: Print "Enter operator ( +,-,*,/,==,>=,<=,!=,<,>,-1 for negation}: "
        cout << "Enter operator (+,-,*,/,==,>=,<=,!=,<,>,-1 for negation): ";
        // read in operator string.
        cin >> opr;
        valid_op = map_operator (opr);

        if(valid_op == -1)
        {
            cout << "Invalid operator!\n";
            goto label1;
        }

        if(valid_op == 0)
        {
            r2.set(-1,1);
            cout << "Enter the operand (ex. 1/2 or -3/4): ";

            cin >> r1;
            /*
            if(!isitvalid)
            {
                cout << "Invalid rational format\n";
                r1.set(0,1);
            }

            //r2.set(-1,1);
            */
            cout << "-(" <<r1<<")=";
            evaluate_operator(valid_op, r1, r2);
        }

        else
        {
            // ToDo: Get operands as rationals using the operator>> 
            cout << "Enter the two operands (ex. 1/2 or -3/4): ";
            //cin >> r1 >> r2;
            cin >> r1;
            cin.clear();
            cin >> r2;
            cout << "(" <<r1<<")" << opr<<"(" <<r2<<")=";
            evaluate_operator(valid_op, r1, r2);
        }


        // cout << "(" <<r1<<")" << opr<<"(" <<r2<<")=";
        //evaluate_operator(valid_op, r1, r2);

        /*  Testing */
        //r1.set(2,3);
        //cout << r1;

        // ToDo: Big multiway-if or switch statement with every operator to evaluate
        // and print the answer using operator<< ex. (n1/d1)+(n2/d2)=n2/d3


        // Use this in case the operator>> fails.
        if (cin.fail()) 
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }


        // ToDo: Prompt the user to rerun the simulation 
        label1:
        cout << "Continue(y/n): ";
        cin >> rerun; 
        cin.ignore(256,'\n');
        cout << endl;

    } while (rerun == 'y'|| rerun == 'Y'); 

    cout << "Have a nice day!" <<endl;

    return 0;
}

// This function will print the menu of operators in the order they appear in the vector map.
string operator_menu()
{
    string op_str;
    vector <string> operators = { "-1", "+", "-", "*", "/", "==", ">=", "<=", "!=", "<", ">"};
    for (int i=1; i < operators.size()-1; i++)
    {
        op_str += operators[i] + ",";
    }
    op_str += operators[operators.size()-1];
    return op_str;
}

// This function maps an operator string to an integer for evaluate_op function.
//Precondition: the user enters a string containing an operator 
//Postcondition: returns a int that either maps to a operator or -1, if not found 
//@param op: the string containing the operator that the user inputs
int map_operator (string op)
{  
    vector <string> operators = { "-1", "+", "-", "*", "/", "==", ">=", "<=", "!=", "<", ">"};
    for (int i=0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        //if it maps to an operator, it is valid and returns an int of the operator position 
        //in the vector 
        if (operators.at(i) == op)
        {
            return i;
        } 
    }
    return -1; //valid operator not found  
}

// This function evaluates an operator given by the valid_op and operands a and b
// @params: valid_op is the int returned from map_operator function giving the correct operator
// @params: a and b are rationals
// prints the result of applying the opertor to the operands.
void evaluate_operator(int valid_op, Rational a, Rational b)
{
    Rational c;
    //the returned number in valid_op decides which operator to implement 
    switch (valid_op){
        case 0: //-1 
            c = a * b;//b = -a; err
            c.simplify();
            cout << c << endl;

            break; 
        case 1: //"+"
            c = a+b;
            c.simplify();
            cout << c <<endl;
            break;
        case 2: //"-"
            c = a - b;
            c.simplify();
            cout << c << endl;
            break;
        case 3: //"*"
            c= a*b;
            c.simplify();
            cout << c << endl;
            break;
        case 4: //"/"
            c=a/b;
            c.simplify();
            cout << c <<endl;
            break;
        case 5: //"=="
            if (a == b){
                cout << "True" <<endl;
            }
            else{
                cout << "False" <<endl;
            }
            break;
        case 6: //">="
            if ( a >= b){
                cout << "True" <<endl;
            }
            else{
                cout << "False" <<endl;
            }
            break;
        case 7: //"<="
            if ( a <= b){
                cout << "True" <<endl;
            }
            else{
                cout << "False" <<endl;
            }
            break;
        case 8: //"!="
            if ( a != b){
                cout << "True" <<endl;
            }
            else{
                cout << "False" <<endl;
            }
            break;
        case 9: //"<"
            if ( a < b){
                cout << "True" <<endl;
            }
            else{
                cout << "False" <<endl;
            }
            break;
        case 10: //">"
            if ( a > b){
                cout << "True" <<endl;
            }
            else{
                cout << "False" <<endl;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (i=0` should be `if (i==0`

Comment: nice catch but issue still persists